# Receiving error "no matching function for call to pow(double)"

Tags: c++

I'm making a code that will calculate interest on a savings account. I listed all my variables as Double. I compiled it before writing the cout prompts at the bottom, and now that my code is finished, it won't compile. It gives me an error. I tried messing with the amount of parentheses, but nothing helped. Here is my code

```
FinalBalanceDaily = StartingPrinciple*(pow(1+((SimpInt/100)/365),(365*T)));
FinalBalanceMonthly = StartingPrinciple*(pow(1+((SimpInt/100)/12),(12*T)));
```

This is the error message.

:55: error: no matching function for call to âpow(double)â

and then it gives notes. The thing is, those two lines are on lines 53 and 54, 55 uses the exp function.

```
FinalBalanceCont = StartingPrinciple*(exp((SimpInt/100)*T));
EffectiveSimpInt1=(exp(SimpInt*T)-1)/T;
EffectiveSimpInt2=((pow(1+(SimpInt/365),(365*T)))-1)/T;
EffectiveSimpInt3=(pow(1+(SimpInt/12),(12*T))-1)/T;
```

These are the lines that use the pow() function

Comment: It is not those lines, those have two arguments. The error talks about one argument.

Comment: so what should i do? should i add more to the post so people can see?

Comment: Yes, please add few more lines of that part of the code at least

Comment: The [`pow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) function takes *two* arguments, so `pow(double)` with *one* argument does not match any known signature.

Comment: they all have 2 arguments. Have I overloaded it with parentheses?

Comment: Indeed .. are you sure that is the exact code? The comma operator applied wrong or a closing parenthesis applied too early could do that, but I can't reason out why it would only parse as a single argument.

Comment: I tried all the different suggestions but I'm still getting the same error. If i hover over (1+simpint, 12*T), they are highlighted red either (double x, double y) in the text box

Comment: Which compiler, and how is it invoked? As you absolutely sure the *correct* file is being edited/compiled?

Comment: im using dev c++ for windows, though I started this code using gedit. I'm positive I'm compiling the correct file because it is the only one in the directory.

Comment: ok... Using the compiler in Dev C++, it compiles. I was using an ssh secure shell remotely accessed from home to try and compile it. As you may have gleaned from this, I am a novice at this stuff, but thanks all for your patience and help.

Answer (score 8):

std::pow() need two parameters, but you just give one

I suggest that you can make your code more readable:

```
double x = 1 + (SimpInt / 100) / 12;
double y = 12 * T;

FinalBalanceMonthly = StartingPrinciple * pow(x, y);
```

By the way, I think that you put your "()" on the wrong place

Comment: In initialisation of `x`, there's a `)` too much.

Comment: As far as I can tell the *shown code* has two parameters, stylistic/complexity concerns aside.