# Compound interest rate formula

Tags: c++, algorithm, formula

This is so frustrating. I can't find this answer anywhere and I can't figure it out myself. This is for an assignment in a college class. We're supposed to have a result of:

> In 10 years, $100 deposited per month will grow to $17793.03

How can I calculate this using c++?

Comment: You need to find a formula then implement it in c++

Comment: What about interest rate?

Comment: Here's an answer in Google Spreadsheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wi8_m1nQWtXhzG6dHFRUeT36vRGO3n5mAG5gAKUNWdI/edit?usp=sharing If you use the numbers (7.5% per annum interest rate, compounded monthly) and formulas in that spreadsheet, you'll quickly figure out how to code that in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Recurring Deposit formula can be applied as

```
M = R * ( (1+r/p)^n-1 )/( (1+r/p) -1) = R * p/r * ( (1+r/p)^n-1 )

M is Maturity value
R is deposit amount
r is rate of interest
p is the number of parts of the year that is used, i.e., p=4 for quarterly and p=12 for monthly, 
n is the number of payments, i.e., the payment schedule lasts n/p years, and then r is the nominal annual interest rate, used in r/p to give the interest rate over each part of the year
```

A working code is as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double r = 7.5 / 100;
    int n = 120;
    int p = 12;
    int R = 100;
#if 0
    double result = 0;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
    {
        result *= ( 1 + r/p ) ;
        result += R;
    }
#else
    double result = R * (p/r )* ( pow( (1+r/p), n ) - 1 );
#endif
    std::cout<<result;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = P (1 + r/n) ^ nt
```

This is the formula for compound interest compounded annually.

```
A = the future value of the investment/loan, including interest
P --> Principal amount (The starting amount)
r --> rate (%)
n --> the number of times that interest is compounded per year
t --> t = the number of years the money is invested or borrowed for
```

Use the above formula and replace the values and let the computer do the rest.
I hope this helps you . Im just a beginner. This is the way i think i would do it.

***edit***

Sorry but the formula i earlier mentioned was incorrect for such a question.
This the correct formula:-

```
PMT * (((1 + r/n)^nt - 1) / (r/n))

PMT--> Principal amount deposited monthy (100 $)
```

Rest of the values remain the same . Try this and store the value in double. This should work. I tried this in codeblocks. Be careful with the values and brackets.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I plugged numbers into your formula and got an incorrect solution `cout << pow(100 * (1 + 0.075/12), 12 * 10);`

Comment: I think the power is raised only on (1+r/n) and not on p. Try that and let me know

Comment: I get the error `no matching function to call for pow(double)`. Using the code `cout << 100 * (pow(1 + 0.075/12), 12);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516045/receiving-error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-powdouble              Refer to this thread. And try different compilers if you can .

Comment: Read carefully: `(pow(1 + 0.075/12, 12))`

Comment: Yes MBo is right, pow requires two parameters but you have given only 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto balance = 0.0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 120; ++i)
        balance = balance * (1 + 0.075/12) + 100;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(7) << balance << '\n';
}
```